# ComboBox: Adding Text to 0 th index

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

i tried to add "Selection Option" Text to 0 th index in ComboBox  but it showing blank

```
public void BindDdlPartyAccount()
    {
        PartyAccount objDDlBind = new PartyAccount();
        List<PartyAccount> ListDdlParty = new List<PartyAccount>();
        ListDdlParty = objDDlBind.getDDlPartyDetails();
        objDDlBind.selectOption = "Select Option";
        objDDlBind.selectOptionId = 0;
        ListDdlParty.Insert(objDDlBind.selectOptionId, objDDlBind);
        ddlEditPartyAcc.DataSource = ListDdlParty;
        ddlEditPartyAcc.ValueMember = "PAId";
        ddlEditPartyAcc.DisplayMember = "name";
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add with the custom object type

```
istDdlParty = objDDlBind.getDDlPartyDetails();
objDDlBind.name= "Select Option";
```

Comment: yes its working, but why cant add like setting objDDlBind.selectOption = "Select Option";

Comment: because your display member property is name